# How can I get data from mongoDB between a certain date (date is stored as createdOn in our document)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This my query -

```
  var Query = Offer
    .where('isDeleted').equals(false)
    .populate('country')
    .populate('state')
    .populate('city')
    .populate('store')
    .populate("createdBy")
    .populate("main_cat")
    .populate("grab_by")
    .populate("merchant_id")
    .sort('store_name');

if (typeof querydata.country != 'undefined' && querydata.country !== '') {
    Query.where('country').in(querydata.country)
}
if (querydata.state.length > 0) {

    querydata.state = querydata.state.split(",");
    Query.where('state').in(querydata.state);
}
if (querydata.city.length > 0) {
    querydata.city = querydata.city.split(",");
    Query.where('city').in(querydata.city);
}
//here i am trying to get data from start to end date
if ((req.query.start_date !== '' && typeof req.query.start_date !== 'undefined') && (req.query.end_date !== '' && typeof req.query.end_date !== 'undefined')) {
    var startdate = new Date(req.query.start_date);
    var enddate = new Date(req.query.end_date);
    //(startdate);
    enddate.setDate(enddate.getDate() + 1);
    Query.where(('createdOn').split('T')[0]).gte(startdate).lte(enddate);
}
```

In the last if else condition I am trying where I am trying to get between start date and end date. Please suggest how should I write my query for the same. Should I use momentJS for the same.
The main purpose of this code is to get the data between a date which will be downloaded by the user in CSV format.

This is the schema of the document: [image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) and [`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) operators to filter data on a range of date.

In your case to search in `Offer` collection the query will be:

```
db.Offer.find({createdOn: {$gte: ISODate('START_DATE'),$lte: ISODate('END_DATE')}})
```

As you are using MongoDB Compass just put following in the `filter` the filter field: (in Schema tab)

```
{createdOn: {$gte: ISODate('START_DATE'),$lte: ISODate('END_DATE')}}
```

Comment: how should i write it in javascript ?

Comment: depends on the db driver you are using. I've added the Mongo Shell command as well as the Compass filter command

Comment: how should i write it in javascript (NodeJS) as a query (like this Query.where('city').in(querydata.city); ) ? I want to pass it in a single query which already is made, not make another one.